# CompizConfig not working

Tags: 12.04, compiz, launcher

The Unity launcher and panel reset they're color to chameleon after restart.I've tried it on several versions of 12.04(12.04,12.04.1,12.04.2).
Reinstalled Úbuntu because it was freezing on shutdown(no solution found).
After first reinstallment I had problems with constant crashing of plymouth(every 5-10 mins) so I installed Ubuntu again, this time the splash screen was missing on boot,annoying like ....,reinstalled it again,this time messed ubuntu up cause install of compiz config frozen and forced shutdown(messed my sistem completely), now I cannot se a color for launcher don't know why.Im reinstalling and reinstalling since yesterday.(for different reasons)

Answer (score 0):

## Reset Compiz

Issue this command in Terminal:

> rm -r ~/.config/compiz-1; rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1; rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1; rm -r ~/.compiz-1; compiz --replace

Comment: still not working it only managed to annoy me.but thanks for the try, the only thing it doesn't remembering is the color.also,to add, after i log in it loads the color i selected but it returns to chameleon

Comment: Tried MyUnity, but same issues after second restart.(color doesnt remain active,other options remain).

Comment: Have to add that it might be related to deluge(torrent client) or errors on boot.

Comment: If this code doesn't fix it, that means there is no problem with compiz.

Comment: This is wrong >"....this time messed ubuntu up cause install of compiz config frozen and forced shutdown(messed my sistem completely")   What do you mean by the installation of compiz?

Comment: My bad forgot to update comments, the Compiz Config Settings Manager,I was installing it after a fresh install,BUT, when I pressed to install it from ubuntu software center, appearantly it started installing the updates also(500 updates because I installed a fresh 12.04 and not 12.04.2) and I thought something is wrong and I forced a reboot.Hope you understood now?Also found on the internet that i can try unity --reset but still didn't worked,only reseted compiz settings.

Comment: Adi, if you ran the above command, your all compiz settings will be reset back to factory settings. That's all I can tell you...